# static createXel function not working properlly

Tags: javascript

I am working on a small framework. I made it, so i can handle everything in it. I got one problem tho...

This function just wont work. I am not going to show the full code, I just want to know, if I made anything wrong within this function.

```
static createXel(element, attributes) {
        var htmlelement;
        if (element == "h1" 
            element == "h2" 
            element == "h3" 
            element == "h4" 
            element == "h5" 
            element == "h6") {
            htmlelement = 'HTMLHeadingElement';
        } else {
            htmlelement = HTMLElementsArr[element];
        }
```

Comment: Your [original revision](//i.stack.imgur.com/K02cR.png) definitely had the `||` operators in place. This is a question based on a typo — off-topic and not useful for Stack Overflow. Besides, what is the purpose of this function? Why not use `document.createElement`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had to add "||" for it to work, so it looks like this.

```
   static createXel(element, attributes) {
        var htmlelement;
        if (element == "h1" ||
            element == "h2" ||
            element == "h3" ||
            element == "h4" ||
            element == "h5" ||
            element == "h6") {
            htmlelement = 'HTMLHeadingElement';
        } else {
            htmlelement = HTMLElementsArr[element];
        }
```